# how to set android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_drawable_selector" through java in android?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

How to  set

```
 android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_drawable_selector"
```

through java for a **RadioButton** in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), since RadioButton is a subclass of `TextView`. E.g.

`radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (0, R.drawable.your_drawable_selector, 0, 0)`.

If you have a Bitmap you can use

```
Drawable drawable =  new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap);
radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
```

From the documentation

> Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the
>   right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable
>   there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

Comment: what if I have a bitmap?

Comment: thats not working, I just tried and then I got the error "The method radioButtonsetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, Drawable, null, null) is undefined for the type RadioButton"

Comment: I forgot a `.`  `radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`